# Best way for connecting to two databases using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I want to connect to two databases.
The first one is the old database.
The second one is the new database.

I have to transfer the data from the old database to the new database and at the first place I want to know how to make a properly written database connection in php using PDO

> This code below is what I have got so far

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$olddb = array (
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'dbname' => 'old',
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => ''
);

try
{
    $olddb = new PDO('mysql:host='.$olddb['host'].';dbname='.$olddb['dbname'], $olddb['user'], $olddb['pass']);
    $olddb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $olddb->query("SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $errormessage = '<p> 
            Regelnummer: '.$e->getLine().'<br /> 
            Bestand: '.$e->getFile().'<br /> 
            Foutmelding: '.$e->getMessage().' 
        </p>';

    trigger_error($errormessage);
}

$newdb = array (
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'dbname' => 'new',
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => ''
);

try
{
    $newdb = new PDO('mysql:host='.$newdb['host'].';dbname='.$newdb['dbname'], $newdb['user'], $newdb['pass']);
    $newdb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $newdb->query("SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $errormessage = '<p> 
            Regelnummer: '.$e->getLine().'<br /> 
            Bestand: '.$e->getFile().'<br /> 
            Foutmelding: '.$e->getMessage().' 
        </p>';

    trigger_error($errormessage);
}
```

Comment: Are both databases on the same server?

Comment: It's not clear what question you're asking. Please revise your question to make clear what type of answers you're looking for. What happens when you run the code you've provided?

Answer (score 1):

If both databases are on the same server, you don't need to make two PDO connections. The database specified in the PDO DSN is just the default, but you can access other databases using a prefix before the table name. If the schema for the two tables is the same, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO newdb. gebruikers
SELECT * FROM olddb. gebruikers
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for the code to transfer the database from the old one to the new one would be something like this below:

```
try 
{ 
    $query = " 
    SELECT * FROM gebruikers "; 

    $olddb_users = $olddb->prepare($query); 
    $olddb_users->execute(); 

    while($olddb_user = $olddb_users->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {  


    $query = "
     INSERT INTO gebruikers (id, gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord, naam, adres, plaats) 
        VALUES (:id, :gebruikersnaam, :wachtwoord, :naam, :adres, :plaats) 
        ";

    $newdb_user = $newdb->prepare($query); 

    $newdb_user->bindParam(':id', $olddb_user['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $newdb_user->bindParam(':gebruikersnaam', $olddb_user['gebruikersnaam'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $newdb_user->bindParam(':wachtwoord', $olddb_user['wachtwoord'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $newdb_user->bindParam(':naam', $olddb_user['naam'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $newdb_user->bindParam(':adres', $olddb_user['adres'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $newdb_user->bindParam(':plaats', $olddb_user['plaats'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 

    $newdb_user->execute(); 

    $newdb_user_id = $newdb->lastInsertId();


    } 
}

catch(PDOException $e) 
{ 
    $errormessage = '<p> 
            Regelnummer: '.$e->getLine().'<br /> 
            Bestand: '.$e->getFile().'<br /> 
            Foutmelding: '.$e->getMessage().' 
        </p>'; 

    trigger_error($errormessage); 
}
```

I have a feeling that I miss something. I am not sure if the lastinsertid is written good.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? It looks like it's part of the question, so you should edit it into the question.

Comment: Since you're inserting the `id` explicitly, `lastInsertId()` won't work. That's only used when you leave out the auto-incremented column and the database assigns it automatically.